# How can I call this function only once yet loop as needed?

Tags: javascript

I have a Chrome extension that replaces certain phrases on webpages. It uses a 2 dimensional array. The [i][1] replaces the text in provided in the [i][0] value.

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    findAndReplaceDOMText(document.body, {
      preset: 'prose',
      find: array[i][0],
      replace: array[i][1]
    });
}
```

This code works fine yet it seems computationally expensive as it calls the `findAndReplaceDOMText` function multiple times rather than just once. Is it possible to move the for loop inside the function to just wrap the `find` and `replace` params? If so what would that look like? I can only get console errors trying this.

Edit: The function traverses the DOM looking for all visible human readable text that contains the regex phrase provided at `find` and replaces with the string provided at `replace`.

Comment: That completely depends on what the function does.

Comment: Use the loop [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

Comment: @SLaks he's using [this project](https://github.com/padolsey/findAndReplaceDOMText)

Comment: Correct, am using the findAndReplaceDOMText code linked by @fixmycode

Comment: "it *seems* computationally expensive" --- or it **IS** expensive? Are you solving a real problem or it's the imaginary one?

Comment: The replace parameter can be a string *or* a function.  You can take advantage of this to do this as a one-pass rather than an n-pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without modifying the function's behaviour, you can't. What you *could* do is separating the find and replace passes.

Your strings are stored in a kind of difficult to transverse way, so let's flat them out:

```
var flatFind = array.map(function(elem){
    return elem[0]
})

var flatReplace = array.map(function(elem){
    return elem[1]
})
```

Then, you'd need to create a regex string that encompasses all your search strings:

```
var searchString = "/("+flatFind.join("|")+")/g"
```

Then pass it to the function, using a function to find the index of the match:

```
findAndReplaceDOMText(document.body, {
    preset: 'prose',
    find: searchString,
    replace: function(portion, match){
      var idx = flatFind.indexOf(match)
      if(idx > -1) return flatReplace[idx]
      else throw "hey, there's no replacement string for this!"
    }
})
```

Comment: To be safe, `array[i][0]` needs some escaping.

Comment: you're right, but that's for @rorykoehler to determine, let's assume it's just phrases

Comment: Thanks for this. It is very educational. I marked this as the correct answer as it is more detailed than @Matmarbon's though essentially the same answer.

Comment: I missed some parentheses and also if we already had a flat list of search terms why don't use that to create the search string

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this probably won't work in my case because I already have multiple regex phrases for each find (variations of a single phrase) but only one replacement phrase which would throw off the index alignment?  For example I have the following:

    `[/(?:Kim Jong un|Kim Jong Un|Kim Jong-Un|Kim Jong-un)/g, 'Fatty the 3rd']`

Comment: you could then create a function that maps many search strings to one replacement string and use it instead of just mapping 1:1 between search and replacements.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the replace parameter as a function.
The `find`-configuration-property then needs to be a regular expression (`RegExp`-object) constructed of your search strings (like `/first|second|third/g`). Do not forget the `g`-modifier at the end.

As `replace`-configuration-property you then create a function that checks which string occurred (you get that as the second parameter to your function). According to the match you then return the corresponding value (for example if `match` is `"first"` then you return `"1st"`. If `match` is `"second"` then you return `"2nd"` and so on).

Comment: Thanks this was what I was looking for